# vimrc configuration does not apply for python files

Tags: python, vim

I want to use vim for python but I recognized that some of my vimrc settings are not applied for python files but for any other files that I tried yet. For Instance:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
```

other settings in my vimrc however apply properly for python files.

Based on some responses in Stackoverflow I tried replacing the section above by:

```
set shiftwidth=4
au FileType python set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
au FileType python set tabstop=4
set expandtab
au FileType python set expandtab
```

I also tried reloading the vimrc using `:source ~/.vimrc`, starting the vim using `vim --noplugin hello.py` and setting the configurations above after opening the python file but all didn't help.

Comment: See `:help ft-python-plugin`.

Comment: @romainl, thanks, this solved my problem. However, I do not really understand why it didn't work before because the configuration is similar to how I wanted it to be. From help: "By default the following options are set, in accordance with PEP8: `setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 tabstop=8` To disable this behaviour, set the following variable in your vimrc: `let g:python_recommended_style = 0.` "

Comment: What is the output of `:filetype`?

Comment: @romainl it's "filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON"

Comment: With that you should get the defaults, which are exactly what you want so I have no idea what the problem is, here.